# Hazelcast com.hazelcast.core.MultiTask is absent in v3.8

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using the newest Hazelcast v3.8 and can not found `MultiTask` inside `com.hazelcast.core` package or any other package.

***What is the replacement of `MultiTask` in the newest versions of Hazelcast?***

I want to controll on which physical nodes my task are run. I have found a nice example of [Hazelcast distributed executor in use](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.3/manual/html/ch09.html).

You can see there nice example:

```
public void echoOnMembers(String input, Set<Member> members) throws Exception {
   MultiTask<String> task = new MultiTask<String>(new Echo(input), members);
   ExecutorService executorService = Hazelcast.getExecutorService();
   executorService.execute(task);
   Collection<String> results = task.get();
}
```

Now I want the same code but which will work on v3.8. Please help)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MultiTask` was removed in 3.0 in favour of more expressive, straightforward `ExecutorService` API.  You can use following `IExecutorService` methods:

```
void executeOnMembers(Runnable command, Collection<Member> members);
void executeOnMembers(Runnable command, MemberSelector memberSelector);
void executeOnAllMembers(Runnable command);

<T> Map<Member, Future<T>> submitToMembers(Callable<T> task, Collection<Member> members);
<T> Map<Member, Future<T>> submitToMembers(Callable<T> task, MemberSelector memberSelector);
<T> Map<Member, Future<T>> submitToAllMembers(Callable<T> task);
```

Also there are callback versions of above methods. For more info see:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IExecutorService.html

Drop-in replacement for `echoOnMembers(...)` example is:

```
public void echoOnMembers( String input, Set<Member> members ) throws Exception {
  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
  IExecutorService executorService = 
      hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService( "default" );

  Map<Member, Future<String>> futures = executorService
      .submitToMembers( new Echo( input ), members );

  for ( Future<String> future : futures.values() ) {
    String echoResult = future.get();
    // ...
  }
}
```

See Hazelcast documentation and code samples for more info:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#executing-code-in-the-cluster

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-executor